# Using PXE Boot to Handle Booting Sequence

Tags: windows, pxe-boot

I am not sure on how to say the question. I still tried though.

Anyways, do any of you guys know how to use PXE Booting to like handle the boot sequence of the computers in a network?

I'll try to explain further. Let's say I have a server that has WDS in it, so that means that I can handle PXE Booting. However, I want it to work in another way such that when a computer in a network is being PXE Booted, it will try to check for a VHD in the server itself and see if it has been altered in any way. If not, then the PXE boot handler will exit the PXE sequence and then proceed to boot to the local hard drive of that computer. However, if the server detected that the VHD file has been altered, it will update the local hard disk (i.e. repartition/reformat/change it), recopy the files that was in the VHD from the server, then after that try to proceed to booting in the local hard drive.

Is there a way to do this? It would be preferable if it can be done using Windows Server instead of Linux. However, if linux really is needed, then I am fine with it. I will just have 2 servers.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SCCM (among many other things) pretty much does the same you describe here.

Comment: Is there any other way other than having to pay a yearly fee? Our Laboratory is in a bit of a tight budget.

Comment: If you need "full" automation you need SCCM, if you can give up some of it you have different PXE alternatives i.e. Serva